# Bootstrap button make to link to another webpage

Tags: c#, webforms, bootstrap-4

I have a bootstarp example of the button i need , howver i want to convert this to link to another web page.

```
            <div class="btn-group btn-group-justified">
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" >Compare Electricity Tariffs</a>
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Compare Gas Tariffs</a>
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Compare Dual Tariffs</a>
            </div>
```

How do i modify this in order to link to my other page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should put you link in the href property of the a tag. Like so:

```
<a href="gastariffs.html" class="btn btn-primary">Compare Gas Tariffs</a>
```